# MyClas::insert($data) not calling ORM save event?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

we are trying to log the changes made to the models via `ORM laravel 5`.

There are default events which we are using to achieve the same like  `static::saving()`, `static::created()` etc.

But when I use insert in below way none of the ORM events are getting triggered.

Working Code:

```
$myclass = new MyClass;
$myclass->save($data);
```

Not working:

```
MyClass::insert()
```

Please assist guyz.

Comment: I think insert does a direct query to the table and it doesn't use or trigger any of the Eloquent methods. Why not use `create()` instead?

Comment: Even i am assuming the same, but i dint find any documentation saying that. Problem here is application is already built and we are plugging in logs in to it now, so trying to find out what does it do exactly and why is it used there.

Comment: I'm thinking you could do a Lravel Macro to overwrite the `insert` or make all the `MyClass` models extend an abstract class which would have an `insert` method where you can log on every query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Eloquent ORM then `->save()` does not accept any arguments.

Correct way is:

```
$flight = new Flight;
$flight->name = $request->name;
$flight->save();
```

If you are using query builder then you use insert(),

```
DB::table('flights')->insert([
    ['name' => 'Foo', 'emailaddress' => 'abc@abc.com'],
    ['name' => 'Loo', 'emailaddress' => 'test@abc.com']
]);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah! now got an idea on how both of them work! Thanks